# People detection in a supermarket zenital video

Tags: machine-learning, python, descriptive-statistics, scikit-learn

I am programming a people detector in a supermarket environment. I am using a dataset that I built from an example vídeo with 500 people and 500 background pictures which have 128x128 size with HOG descriptors. SVM as classifier with sklearn which gives me a good accuracy. I am using gmm background substraction to reduce the action area in the pictures and then a sliding window in this area. My problem is that it is so slow to be in real time. I am thinking to reduce the vector descriptors or using a different one, another option is to program two classifier one for the background and the other for the people. Ideas? Thank you, I am stuck with this problem. If you could help me.

Comment: In video frames, subtract one from the next to make a difference pane.  That makes all constant value objects go to zero.  Only changes show up.  Algorithm complexity is expressed in "O-notation", for example linear complexity is O(n).  This means that run-time increases linearly with objects.  You are likely living in O(n^3) methods.  First, minimize "n" without compromising the informativeness of the image.  Then you can work on adjusting the algorithm to do the job.  Grayscale.

Comment: Thank you. I am using grayscale alredy. With opencv I load each frame and transform it to one channel with cvtcolor. With gmm background substraction only remains the moving objects and if its area is enough to be a person, I run svm HOG feature extractor and svm classifier on it. But still so slow. Maybe reescaling image?

Comment: which is more expensive 1) running GMM background or 2) subtracting sequential frames?  The subtract is thousands of times faster.  rowsums and colsums would allow you to truncate to only the area of interest for the cost of two image additions.  Do you not have two images of the same scene that are 1/60 a second apart in time?

Comment: Thank you, understood. I will change gmm for sequential substraction. And yes, I have a 5 minutes video, why?

Comment: I asked because I don't know the data available.  If you had one image per 10 minutes then sequential subtraction is not on the menu.